# React.js: convert string to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using react to fetch Json data from an API, however, the API includes a key that has an object formatted as a String. See example below:

```
 user_category:"employee",
 user_info:"{"user_id":"55","user_age":"27","user_company":"tesla"}"
```

To access the user-category, I simply use a `header` with an `accessor`, and the value displays on the table just fine, however I am having difficulties accessing the user_info key String using its keys and values using something like this:

```
 {
     Header: "User Id",
     accessor: "user_info.user_id"
   },
   {
     Header: "User Age",
     accessor: "user_info.user_age"
   },
   {
     Header: "User Company",
     accessor: "user_info.user_company"
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s odd that the server is double-encoding the object to JSON like that (encoding the inner one and then encoding the whole thing).

Ideally you’d have the server-side fixed, because what they’re doing doesn’t make sense, as JSON supports nested objects just fine.

If you have to solve the problem on the client, you’d use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn the string into an object.

```
const atts = {
  user_category: "employee",
  user_info: "{"user_id":"55","user_age":"27","user_company":"tesla"}"
};

const userInfo = JSON.parse(atts.user_info);
```

Comment: I am nut sure I can wrap up the response in an atts constant because it is loaded directly from the server...

Comment: Right. So I’m not familiar with React, but you’ll probably need to make a function that takes in `user_info` (that’s in props or data or something?) and does this parsing.